# How do I program an ItsyBitsy 32u4?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega32u4

How do I load code onto a ItsyBitsy 32u4 without using the graphcial Arduino IDE?

I've looked for "ItsyBitsy 32u4 programmer" and ItsyBitsy 32u4 bootloader".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the AVRDUDE software from command line. See e.g. https://learn.adafruit.com/atmega32u4-breakout/using-with-avrdude